# why is my query showing error regarding Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'

Tags: sql, syntax, where-clause

```
insert into general_info(desig) 
values('professor') 
where g_id = (select h_gid from hasj where h_userid = 'U001');
```

All tables and columns r used correctly yet it shows the following error...

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.

Comment: You cannot have a `WHERE` clause in an `INSERT` statement - what are you trying to do?? Are you really trying to **update** those rows that match that `h_userid` ?? `INSERT` will insert a **new row** - you cannot limit that with a  `WHERE` clause - while `UPDATE` will update **existing row(s)**

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE general_info
set desig= 'professor'
where g_id in (select h_gid from hasj where h_userid = 'U001');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want an `update` query:

```
update general_info set
desig = 'professor'
where g_id in (select h_gid from hasj where h_userid = 'U001');
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for mass insertion:

```
INSERT INTO Table(...)  
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...
```